# ndb Getting Key validation error on StringProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am having a weird message error.

I have a model with a `StringProperty` called `checksum`, but when I try to save to it, I get a validation error claiming that a Key value was expected.

EDIT: to avoid potential issues i renamed the `id` property to `gdid`, as it is displayed now, and the error persists.

```
class gd_file(base_class):
    """Google Drive File Reference"""
    gdid = ndb.StringProperty()
    #creation_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    #modification_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    checksum = ndb.StringProperty()
    size = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    office = ndb.KeyProperty()
    parents = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

sample code:

```
            logging.info('GD_FILE:')
            for p in gd_file._properties:
                logging.info( getattr(gd_file,p))

            logging.info('m:')
            logging.info(type(m))
            logging.info(m)

            fd = gd_file(
                parents = parents_list,
                owners = gd['ownerNames'],
                last_changed_by = gd['lastModifyingUserName'],
                creation_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(cdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
                modification_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(mdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
                gdid = gd['id'],
                name = result['name'],
                size = result['size'],
                type = gd['mimeType'],
                checksum = m
            )
```

Line 231 in my code is where I attribute `checksum = m` above.

Log including error:

```
INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:213] GD_FILE:

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] KeyProperty('parents')

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] StringProperty('checksum')

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] StringProperty('owners', repeated=True)

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] DateTimeProperty('creation_date', auto_now_add=True)

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] StringProperty('type')

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] StringProperty('last_changed_by')

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] StringProperty('name')

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] IntegerProperty('size')

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] DateTimeProperty('modification_date', auto_now=True)

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] KeyProperty('cid')

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] KeyProperty('office')

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:215] StringProperty('id')

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:217] m:

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:218] <type 'str'>

INFO     2014-02-20 21:20:09,042 proterrahandler.py:219] 019f8998e5896bb34ecdbb0803343486

ERROR    2014-02-20 21:20:09,046 webapp2.py:1552] Expected Key, got [u'0B2PeVr8B69LER2ZGWVNjM29TSTQ']

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__

    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__

    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher

    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__

    return handler.dispatch()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch

    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch

    return method(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Tiago\Google Drive\Development\gae\cert-id-tinkerbox\proterrahandler.py", line 89, in post

    files = self.handle_upload()

  File "C:\Users\Tiago\Google Drive\Development\gae\cert-id-tinkerbox\proterrahandler.py", line 231, in handle_upload

    checksum = m

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 2852, in __init__

    self._set_attributes(kwds)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 3587, in _set_attributes

    setattr(self, name, value)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 3605, in __setattr__

    return super(Expando, self).__setattr__(name, value)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1343, in __set__

    self._set_value(entity, value)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1088, in _set_value

    value = self._do_validate(value)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1035, in _do_validate

    value = self._call_shallow_validation(value)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1227, in _call_shallow_validation

    return call(value)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1274, in call

    newvalue = method(self, value)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1927, in _validate

    raise datastore_errors.BadValueError('Expected Key, got %r' % (value,))

BadValueError: Expected Key, got [u'0B2PeVr8B69LER2ZGWVNjM29TSTQ']

INFO     2014-02-20 18:20:09,193 module.py:612] default: "POST /app/proterra/checklist/import HTTP/1.1" 500 3357
```

I am a bit stumped on this one, I have no idea where the Key error is being raised.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think it's related to checksum? The error is complaning about a list containing a string that isn't the same value you're logging. Are you implementing __init__ in your base_class? What is it doing? (I'm guessing the problem is with parents_list, but you'd need to show more code for anyone to be sure!)

Comment: The error is saying it expects a key, and you give it a list of string.

Comment: The error is on the assignment of checksum = m , it is failing in the `_do_validate` call - To be honest I didn't wade through your stacktrace because having an property called id does cause a lot of problems. I suggest you log what type the system thinks the `checksum` property is before you try assigning to it.

Comment: Are you also sure the code you present here is what you are running, you have lines commented out of the class but your setting values for those properties in the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a property called id

It is a argument supplied to the constructor which is used in creating a Key with a supplied id.

Have a read of the ndb.Model docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Constructor

Comment: In fact, this id property never gave me any problem.
Regardless, changing this id property to any other name changes nothing about the error.
I have changed it to `gid` and the error persists.

Comment: Ok, looking further through the stacktrace, it appears we need to see more details of your `base_class` it looks like it is subclass ndb.Expando.  What aren't we seeing here.